# SQL finding part of common and differences under some conditions

Tags: postgresql, join, inner-join

First I will describe the whole idea. I have a system which is storing information about `Projects` going on. Each project have many `Topics`. Each project is revised every month. So for example:

```
2014-01-01 Was added Project '1' in relation of 40 Topics
2014-01-01 Was added Project '2' in relation of 120 Topics
2014-02-01 Was added Project '1' in relation of 30 Topics
2014-02-01 Was added Project '2' in relation of 100 Topics
```

I would like to count differences between topics, how many of them are new, how many of them are ended and how many of them are still on going.

I have tried according to [image]

create a query. 
Tables structure:

```
database=> \d project
                              Tabela "public.project"
    Kolumna     |   Typ   |                      Modyfikatory
----------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------
 id             | integer | niepusty domyĹnie nextval('project_id_seq'::regclass)
 scid           | integer |
 starttime      | date    |


database=> \d topic
                              Tabela "public.topic"
    Kolumna     |   Typ   |                    Modyfikatory
----------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id             | integer | niepusty domyĹnie nextval('topic_id_seq'::regclass)
 project _id    | integer |
 topicengine_id | integer |
 parameter      | text    |
 description    | text    |
 severity       | text    |
 requirement_id | integer |
 topicparam_id  | integer |
```

My first try was counting `on going` topics with inner join:

```
SELECT t1.id 
FROM   topic t1 
       INNER JOIN topic t2 
               ON t1.id = t2.id 
       INNER JOIN project p1 
               ON p1.id = t1.project_id 
       INNER JOIN project p2 
               ON p2.id = t2.project_id 
WHERE  p1.id = 1101 
       AND p2.id = 1168
```

However each time result is null. Could anyone point me where I am doing the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Topic id seems to be the primary key for topic.
That means join: `t1.id = t2.id` join the record with itself and therefore t1.project_id is equal to  t2.project_id and can't have two values at the same time.
Perhaps you meant joining t1 and t2 on topicengine_id?